# Why does asset creation not work for hidden images?

Tags: image-transforms

Im creating a gallery for Fancybox and only wish to show the first image. The rest are hidden in a container and only referenced so that Fancybox can call on these latter. I've tried two approaches: anchor tag with and without the image tag.

I am sure that this is a recent change as I have been using this technique on earlier craft versions and gettting good results.

```
<div class="hide">
  <a title="{{ image.title }}" href="{{ image.getUrl('wide') }}" class="fb" rel="fb-{{ ind }}">
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl('wide') }}" title="{{ image.title }}" style="display: block!important" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The image is generated but it looks like in a temporary location "...cpresources/transforms..." to which Fancybox doesn't recognise.

Comment: Just found the answer from an old colleague http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8712/cache-coldcache-checking-for-ungenerated-image-transforms/8713#8713

Comment: Wanna add that as an official answer, Eli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [generateTransformsBeforePageLoad](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad) in your config/general.php file.

```
'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,
```

> Configures Craft to generate new image transforms right when getUrl()
>   is called, rather than when the browser first requests the image.